# Comparing each item of two lists in Python not expected answer

Tags: python, list, compare

New to coding and python and started practising with Codewars. One of the Kata is:

Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

So I wrote a little code in Python to compare two lists in python however the answer I get is not what is  expected. It seems like a bug which I can't find.

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    # Check if None is provided
    if array1 is None or array2 is None:
        return False
    else:
        # 1)Sort arrays 2)each item in array 1 is squared and compared 1 to 1 with item in array 2
        return not False in [item in [(x*x) for x in sorted(array1)] for item in sorted(array2)]
```

When I supply

```
a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]
```

I receive as expected all to be True, but when I supply

```
a1 = [2, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 9, 9]
```

I expect to receive [True, False, True] but I am getting back [True, True, True] which is clearly very bizarre and I can't understand why. Is it the list comprehension method that gives the problem?

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: `a1[0]^2` is `a2[0]`. `a1[1]^2` is `a2[0]`. `a1[2]^2` is `a2[2]`. So your algorithm is working just fine.

Comment: Did you try to write the list comprehension as a *regular* for loop printing stuff in the loop to see what might be happening? `regardless of the order` - seems each `a1` item squared **is** in `a2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list comprehension is the equivalent of a for loop inside another for loop.  So sorting those does not really matter because you always check all items of array1 on every iteration of array2.

For example, `[item in [(x*x) for x in sorted(array1)] for item in sorted(array2)]`, if `array1 = [2, 2, 3]` and `array2 = [4, 9, 9]` then your example is equivalent to `[item in [2*2, 2*2, 3*3] for item in [4, 9, 9]]`.  Since 4 is in the list twice, 9 is in the list once, and again 9 is in the list once then you get `[True, True, True]`.

Using a list comprehension and enumerate, you could do something like `len(array1) == len(array2) and not False in [array1[index] * array1[index] == array2[index] for index, item in enumerate(array2)]`.  You must check the lengths match to prevent an IndexError.

Comment: Well, thank you so much for the explanation. I didn't know list comprehension works that way. The enumerate method is great.

Comment: Just to add also that the arrays need to be sorted before the looping.